# Calling ERB recursively with binding results in lost output text

Tags: ruby, binding, erb, templating

(Note: I am using Ruby's `erb`, not that of Rails.)

When using the current binding to resolve an ERB template from within another ERB template, the text of the outer template that precedes the call to the inner one is lost.

For example:

`inner.erb` file content:

```
inner
```

`outer.erb` file content:

```
outer
<%= ERB.new(File.read('inner.erb')).result(binding) %>
outer
```

Test script `erb-test` (must do `chmod +x erb-test`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'erb'

puts ERB.new(File.read('outer.erb')).result
```

The output of `./erb-test` is:

```
inner

outer
```

As shown, the first 'outer' string specified in the `outer.erb` template file is lost.
If we remove the `binding` from the ERB call in `outer.erb`:

```
<%= ERB.new(File.read('inner.erb')).result %>
```

...then we now see the first `outer` specified in the outer template:

```
outer
inner

outer
```

Is this a bug? How do you recommend addressing this? I realize it's better to limit the state available to templates, and usually I do that using `ERB#result_with_hash`, but in the case of a sub-template, that is, a template called from another template, it seems reasonable to me that the inner template inherit the binding of the outer template, since it is already limited.

Comment: This is weird. I can verify this behavior but I do not understand how the missing `outer` relates to `binding`. Nothing here is "bound" ... there are no variables in play, right?

Comment: I think the issue is that the ERB code is storing the processed string in an instance variable as it builds it, and when the binding that contains that `self` context and therefore that instance variable is passed to ERB again to build an inner string, that variable is initialized to the empty string before beginning. Thus the need to specify a different variable.

Answer (score 2):

This can be fixed by using the [`eoutvar` parameter to `ERB.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new), as follows:

```
<%= ERB.new(File.read('inner.erb'), eoutvar: '@inner').result(binding) %>
```

Comments in the ERB source code explain it further:

```
# _eoutvar_ can be used to set the name of the variable ERB will build up
# its output in.  This is useful when you need to run multiple ERB
# templates through the same binding and/or when you want to control where
# output ends up.  Pass the name of the variable to be used inside a String.
```

After changing the content of `outer.erb` to:

```
outer
<%= ERB.new(File.read('inner.erb'), eoutvar: '@inner').result(binding) %>
outer
```

...the result is:

```
outer

inner

outer
```

Do be aware that if you were passing unnamed parameters in the constructor call, you will need to use the named approach instead, e.g. for trim mode:

```
    ERB.new(File.read(erb_filespec), eoutvar: eoutvar, trim_mode: '-')
```

instead of:

```
    template = ERB.new(File.read(erb_filespec), 0, '-')
```